# Recurrence of T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3)

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I've searched online for this but I only seem to find answers for a similar equation:

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + cn
```

But the one I'm trying to solve is:

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3)
```

Base case: We can assume `T(a) = Theta(1)` for any constant `a`.

I've succeeded in proving (by induction) that `T(n) = O(n*log(n))`. I thought the answer should be `Theta(n*log(n))`, but I cannot prove that `T(n) = Omega(n*log(n))`.

So my question is - am I correct that the answer is `O(n*log(n))`, and NOT `Theta(n*log(n))`? IF that's true that would really be great...

If I'm wrong I will of course explain where I'm stuck in the induction process...

Thanks!

P.S. If you need to, please try to explain using induction, because I haven't learned all methods for solving these problems yet.

Comment: The solution is not $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Keep trying.  You're on the right path; you just need to keep trying and put in some more effort, and you'll get there.  See if you can guess some other candidate solutions and use guess-and-check to verify them.  If you're really stuck, you can also try solving this for a few simple cases (e.g., what if $T(1)=1$, $T(2)=1$, $T(3)=1$; graph some of the values of $T$; what do you find?).  You can solve this problem using [the techniques in our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755).  I'm going to vote to mark this as a dup of that question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose that $T(m) \leq Cm$ for all $m < n$, and that $n$ is divisible by $3$. Then
$$ T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) \leq C(n/3) + C(2n/3) = Cn. $$
Use this to obtain a good bound on $T(n)$ when $n$ is a power of $3$.